# How to raise or lower text fields in pdf forms?

Tags: pdf, forms, raise

I've been having a misalignment issue between text fields generated with `hyperref` and the corresponding straight lines below them. The attached image illustrates the problem.

[image: Textfields are misaligned with the lines below]

The objective is clear. I would like to lower the text fields so that each text field lies directly above the corresponding straight line. My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
    \begin{Form}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\fontsize{12}{24}\selectfont
\hspace*{2cm} \TextField[name=First and Last Name, width=8cm, borderwidth=1]{}\\
\hspace*{2cm} \rule[-2.5ex]{11.4cm}{0.5pt} \\
\hspace*{2cm} advisor, \hspace{2cm} Date\\
\hspace*{2cm} \TextField[name=First and Last Name, width=8cm, borderwidth=1]{}\\
\hspace*{2cm} \rule[-2.5ex]{11.4cm}{0.5pt} \\
\hspace*{2cm} memberA \\
\hspace*{2cm} \TextField[name=First and Last Name, width=8cm, borderwidth=1]{}\\
\hspace*{2cm} \rule[-2.5ex]{11.4cm}{0.5pt} \\
\hspace*{2cm} memberB \\
\hspace*{2cm} \TextField[name=First and Last Name, width=8cm, borderwidth=1]{}\\
\hspace*{2cm} \rule[-2.5ex]{11.4cm}{0.5pt} \\
\hspace*{2cm} memberC \\
\hspace*{2cm} \TextField[name=First and Last Name, width=8cm, borderwidth=1]{}\\
\hspace*{2cm} \rule[-2.5ex]{11.4cm}{0.5pt} \\
\hspace*{2cm} memberD \\
    \end{Form}
\end{flushleft}


\end{document}
```

There is always the option of raising the lines but I will have to raise the signature titles (e.g. `advisor`, `memberA`) as well. I would prefer to lower the text fields if possible, since I can always create them by hand using Acrobat if necessary.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: It is done. The code is compilable now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `tabular` along with `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{11.5cm}@{}}
\TextField[name=First and Last Name, width=8cm, borderwidth=1]{}\\\midrule[0.5pt]
advisor, \hspace{2cm} Date\\[2.5ex]
\TextField[name=First and Last Name, width=8cm, borderwidth=1]{}\\\midrule[0.5pt]
memberA\\[2.5ex]
\TextField[name=First and Last Name, width=8cm, borderwidth=1]{}\\\midrule[0.5pt]
 memberB\\[2.5ex]
\TextField[name=First and Last Name, width=8cm, borderwidth=1]{}\\\midrule[0.5pt]
memberC\\[2.5ex]
\TextField[name=First and Last Name, width=8cm, borderwidth=1]{}\\\midrule[0.5pt]
memberD
\end{tabular}
    \end{Form}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct. For reasons of completeness I would like to add the results of my own failed attempt, in order to illustrate different aspects of the problem.

If I use `raisebox`, my code becomes like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
    \begin{Form}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\fontsize{12}{24}\selectfont
\raisebox{-1.0 cm}[2cm]{\TextField[name=First and Last Name, width=8cm, borderwidth=1, charsize=0pt]{} \TextField[name=Date, width=3.7cm, borderwidth=1, charsize=0pt]{}}\\
\rule[-2.5ex]{11.4cm}{0.5pt} \\
advisor, \hspace{7.3cm} Date\\
\hspace*{2cm} \raisebox{-1.0 cm}[2cm]{\TextField[name=First and Last Name, width=8cm, borderwidth=1]{}}\\
\hspace*{2cm} \rule[-2.5ex]{11.4cm}{0.5pt} \\
\hspace*{2cm} memberA \\
\hspace*{2cm} \raisebox{-3.0 cm}{\TextField[name=First and Last Name, width=8cm, borderwidth=1]{}}\\
\hspace*{2cm} \rule[-2.5ex]{11.4cm}{0.5pt} \\
\hspace*{2cm} memberB \\
\hspace*{2cm} \raisebox{-1.0 cm}{\TextField[name=First and Last Name, width=8cm, borderwidth=1]{}}\\
\hspace*{2cm} \rule[-2.5ex]{11.4cm}{0.5pt} \\
\hspace*{2cm} memberC \\
\hspace*{2cm} \raisebox{-1.0 cm}{\TextField[name=First and Last Name, width=8cm, borderwidth=1]{}}\\
\hspace*{2cm} \rule[-2.5ex]{11.4cm}{0.5pt} \\
\hspace*{2cm} memberD \\
    \end{Form}
\end{flushleft}


\end{document}
```

and the results can be seen in the picture. As you can see, trying to lower the text field with `raisebox` does succeed, up to a critical point. After this critical point, instead of the text field alone being lowered, the whole "group" (consisting of the text field, line and signature title) is lowered.

[image: <code>Raisebox</code> works up to a point]

My second observation concerns the solution mentioned above, with `booktabs`, which does work. If I slightly change the code, you will see that the problem is essentially caused by the `rule` command.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{11.5cm}@{}}
\TextField[name=First and Last Name, width=8cm, borderwidth=1]{}\\\rule[-2.5ex]{11.4cm}{0.5pt} 
advisor, \hspace{2cm} Date\\[2.5ex]
\TextField[name=First and Last Name, width=8cm, borderwidth=1]{}\\\midrule[0.5pt]
memberA\\[2.5ex]
\TextField[name=First and Last Name, width=8cm, borderwidth=1]{}\\\midrule[0.5pt]
memberB\\[2.5ex]
\TextField[name=First and Last Name, width=8cm, borderwidth=1]{}\\\midrule[0.5pt]
memberC\\[2.5ex]
\TextField[name=First and Last Name, width=8cm, borderwidth=1]{}\\\midrule[0.5pt]
memberD
\end{tabular}
\end{Form}


\end{document}
```

[image: Demonstration of the problem caused by <code>rule</code>]